# Are there bags for shower stuff?

Tags: tips-and-tricks, gear, hygiene

My university is in a different city than the city that I live in. I have one class this semester. Thus, I have to travel every week one day.

My problem is that every week I have to pack my shower stuff, such as shampoo, hair gel, body soap, deodorant etc.

I need to know if there is a specific bag for that. I am asking about a small (supposed) bag specially for these stuff.

I know that I can buy any small bag that suits me, but first I would like to know if there is a standard thing for this.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, bags are sold specifically for this purpose. Features may include:

- being waterproof
- having lots of compartments to hold many small bottles (or one compartment with various elastics and such to hold small bottles sort of upright)
- having at least one compartment to hold tiny little things like bandaids and safety pins
- having a hook so you can hang it up in a small bathroom

Examples:

[image]
[image]
[image]

The magic word is "toiletries", "wash", "Dopp" or "washing" bag or kit (depending on where you live and to some extent your gender, though the bags are generally gender neutral.) Search with that and you should find a ton. Or go into a department store and take a look in the luggage section.

Comment: may I ask for a picture of what you are trying to say? a good brand?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=toiletry+bag&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0CAgQ_AUoAmoVChMIzuC-99v3yAIVx0uICh3T1AJL&biw=1225&bih=748

Comment: Guess I'm the only lazy person who chucks everything in a plastic bag then

Comment: They are also sometimes called [Dopp Kits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dopp_kit), especially for men. That Wikipedia article lists a few other names. They come in many shapes and sizes, with some providing lots of small compartments and others giving more flexible space. Travelers will often use them with travel-sized soaps, shampoo, etc..., either [empty bottles](http://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/MTYwMFgxNjAw/z/Cj4AAOSwDk5T~061/$_35.JPG?set_id=2) they fill themselves or [prepackaged ones](http://www.minimus.biz/images/icons/Personal-Care-Main.jpg).

Comment: In British English, I'd immediately think of a bag containing laundry if you said "washing" bag. A "wash" bag would contain toiletries.

Comment: Another term used in British English is "sponge bag".  Not as common as it used to be, but I still hear it from time to time.